# Python random.choice same output

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to random some strings in a variable,

```
myTest = random.choice(["test1","test2","test3"])
print(myTest)
print(myTets)
print(myTest)
```

And when I'm running my script all of them are the same every time,

```
test1
test1
test1
```

I like to random my variable every time I'm calling it, like,

```
test1
test3
test2
```

Comment: `myTets` is hopefully typo? Also, `random.choice` is not variadic, it needs exactly one parameter (that should be a list): `random.choice(["test1","test2","test3"])`

Comment: For that you have to call random each time you want random string.

Comment: Related: [Updating a parameter's value doesn't update the result of the function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49587299)

Comment: You are repeatedly printing the value of a variable without changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the same as

```
x = 42
print(x)
print(x)
print(x)
```

A variables value only changes when you assign it:

```
x = 42
print(x)
x = 45
print(x)
```

If you want a new random value, you need to call the function again:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = random.choice(l)
print(x)
x = random.choice(l)
print(x)
```

Comment: let me make something clear I have a var.py in that I'm saving my variables and in another python file im trying to read var.myTest

Comment: @ArmanTrb I don't understand what that has to do with your quesiton.

Comment: I made tons of variables like this for my script and now I realized I have this problem so what can I do now

Comment: @ArmanTrb If you cannot adapt my answer directly to your problem, you should edit your question to show a more complex example that illustrates what you have done and explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ArmanTrb If you want the value of `var.myTest` to change, you have to assign it different values. If you assign it only once, then it never changes. Having global variables in `var.py` seems like the incorrect solution to your real problem. I suggest you learn about functions and how to pass arguments to them.

Comment: @ArmanTrb It doesn't matter if you have thousand variables like this. It also doesn't matter what you're doing with those variables. You have to call `random.choice` every time you want to pick a random element. There's no way around that. You can, however, write a function like `def random_greeting(): return random.choice(['Hi', 'Greetings', 'Welcome'])` and then simply call that function whenever you need a random greeting: `print(random_greeting())`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the command each time:

```
myTest = random.choice(["test1","test2","test3"])
print(myTest)
myTest = random.choice(["test1","test2","test3"])
print(myTest)
myTest = random.choice(["test1","test2","test3"])
print(myTest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this...

```
print(random.choice("test1","test2","test3"))
print(random.choice("test1","test2","test3"))
print(random.choice("test1","test2","test3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [random.sample docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). In your case that can look like this:

```
import random
my_tests = ['test1','test2','test3']
for choice in random.sample(my_tests, 3):
    print(choice)
```

Other option is to do that in place, in other words - by changing `my_tests`:

```
import random
my_tests = ['test1','test2','test3']
print(my_tests, '\n\n')
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(my_tests)
    print(my_tests)
```

Comment: That won't repeat a value, though, so it's not the same as calling `choice` in the loop. Of course, the OP might actually want that. And if they do, another option is to call `shuffle` on the list, if you don't mind shuffling the original list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the results to be used somewhere instead of just printing, you should just use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), the values will be stored directly in a new list.

Interpreter:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> choices = ["test1","test2","test3"]
>>> selected = [random.choice(choices) for _ in range(3)] # iterates 3 times, appending value of "random.choice(choices)" to the end of the list
>>> print(selected)
['test1', 'test2', 'test2']
```

By the way, "_" is just "I don't care" variable used to store values that you don't need, if you needed the number, you'd use name it a proper variable like "i" and use it.

EDIT: Also after your question is answered, please select the answer that helped you to solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` will try to call `__str__()` for an object if it does not know how to print it. You can use this to emulate the behaviour of a random variable in `print()` by wrapping `random.choice()`:

```py
import random

class MyTest:
    def __init__(self, choices):
        self.choices = choices
    def __str__(self):
        return str(random.choice(self.choices))

myTest = MyTest(["test1","test2","test3"])

print(myTest)
print(myTest)
print(myTest)
```

This also works for use of the variable in formatted strings, e.g. `print(f'>{myTest}<')` but fails with operators such as string concatenation:

```py
>>> print(f'>{myTest}<')
>test3<
>>> print(myTest+'!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MyTest' and 'str'
```

You could fix the latter by adding a function `__add__(self, x)` to `MyTest` that returns `str(self)+x` but this wouldn't enable using `'!'+myTest`.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to import your random variable. Then you should put your test1, test2 and test3 in one string. then you can get the result you are looking for like this:

```
import random
myTest = random.choice(["test1, test2, test3"])
print(myTest)
```

Comment: Repeating `print(myTest)`, there is no variation in the output and the output is not of the form indicated as an example of desired output in the question. The first line imports the Python module `random`, not a "random variable".